# update-grub ignores GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub when generating menu.lst

Tags: kernel, grub-legacy

I created `/etc/default/grub` with the contents `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"`. When I run `update-grub`, I expect these additional arguments to be appended to the kernel lines in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`. But it never works.

I tried several variants (`GRUB_CMDLINE_{XEN,LINUX}{_DEFAULT}`) but no luck. The file `/etc/default/grub` *does* get executed, tried it with an test echo output. When (un)installing kernels, `menu.lst` always gets updated. But the above arguments are always ignored.

Do you have any ideas to debug this? I'm out of ideas.

System info:

- Ubuntu 14.04 x64
- grub 0.97-29ubuntu66
- It's an Xen DomU booted via pvgrub64

Answer (score 0):

According to this [ServerFault discussion](https://serverfault.com/a/447824), Grub2 uses `/etc/default/grub` and generates `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Grub v0.97 doesn't use that file, and `/boot/grub/menu.lst` is untouched by `update-grub` (or it should be).